# Should all table storage requests share the CloudTable reference

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-table-storage

As title suggests, I'm wondering whether all of my requests to table storage should share a reference to my `CloudTable` or not, I can't find documentation anywhere that covers this.

**Example 1 (a `CloudTable` per request):**

```
 public async Task MakeTableStorageRequest()
        {
                var operation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(...);
                var myTableReference = _cloudTableClient.GetTableReference(TableReference);
                await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(insertOrMergeOp).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

**Example 2 (a `CloudTable` (singleton?) constructed once and shared):**

```
public MyClass()
{
  ...
  _cloudTableRef = _cloudTableClient.GetTableReference("Some Table");
}

 public async Task MakeTableStorageRequest()
        {
                var operation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(...);
                await _cloudTableRef .ExecuteAsync(insertOrMergeOp).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

CloudTable and CloudTableClient are thread-safe and you can use them in singleton or through single instance. At the same time its not recommended to create instances per request as it could lead to memory leak if instances are not disposed properly.

You can read more on below threads as well:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-table-dotnet/issues/10

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/629